# Does the carbocation rearrangement in a SN1 reaction specify a change in degree?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

I am asked to determine whether the following process is likely to involve a carbocation rearrangement or not:

> [image: impossible rearrangement]

I think it is possible through the rearrangement given above (though the rearrangement cannot become a secondary or primary carbocation). Can someone please clarify if the carbocation rearrangement specifies a change in degree?

Comment: I feel your wording is a bit unclear. Do you mean to ask that whether this rearrangement is possible and whether it will be called a carbocation rearrangement even though there is no change in the degree of the carbocation?

Comment: How do you say the rearrangement cannot become a secondary or primary carbocation? And as Binary Geek there is no change inthe degree of the carbocation provide sime clarity. By what reference your thinking it is possible ?

Comment: What I get of your question, the process you have made is not possible. It will help if you c;arify.

Comment: Try to draw the mechanism for the second transformation and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Yes @BinaryGeek I mean to ask whether it will be called a carbocation rearrangement even though it doesn't become a primary or secondary carbocation, and instead remains a tertiary carbocation.

Comment: @imaginov I suggest you to add your last comment into your question to clarify it.

Comment: @jerepierre That's why I added `~ ?` to the arrow when I replaced the drawing ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common carbocation rearrangements involve [1,2] hydride or alkyl shifts. As a typical result a secondary carbocation is converted to a more stabilized tertiary carbocation.

**In the course of these reactions, the migrating group and the positive charge change place, they move to opposite directions.**

This is not the case in your example.

I fail to see how your transformation can be described as a cationic rearrangement!

Comment: Looks like the OP added [some info](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31427/does-the-carbocation-rearrangement-in-a-sn1-reaction-specify-a-change-in-degree#comment45629_31427)  in the comments after you answered the question. It would be good if you do so :)